# Rotate and Drag (if dragging don't rotate, else rotate) Problem Unity 2D (Not Solved)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am moving my object with `onDrag`, but there is a situation like this: I do not want to execute a drag if the sprites are rotating, but if the sprites are not rotating, I want drag to be executed. The Unity 2d code is shown below.

```
 if (!drag)
         {
             if (rota < 13)
             {
                 rota = rota + 0.5f;
                 //rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta;
                 mPosDelta = eventData.delta - mprevpos;
                 transform.Rotate(0, 0, rota, Space.Self);    
             }
             else
             {
                 this.gameObject.transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler(0, 0,180);
                 Invoke("Wait",3f);
 
                
             }
         }
         else
         {
             
             rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta;
         }
```

Comment: What is the behaviour that you are experiencing?

Comment: sprite is always dragging , i can't rotate

Comment: @maksymiuk how should i go about it?

Comment: i'm assuming this is all in the `update` function? and `onDrag` sets the `drag` boolean to true? and somewhere you set also setting `drag` to false? Is this true? also is `rectTransform` your sprite?

Comment: rectTransform my sprite

Comment: I tried to return bool value to try something but it doesn't work

Comment: where do you set `drag` to true?

Comment: Update inside the code block

Comment: are you sure it ever gets called? try breakpoint on that line and make sure it actually gets called. Can you show that part in your question?

Comment: I've created a double button with a pointer right now, I'm trying to set it to be rotated if it is held by the edges, if it tries I will share the code :) Thanks for your help

Comment: I still can't solve the whole problem I am adding it here

Answer (score 0):

[image]

EDIT:this will rotating the ball and make 6

so if it turns it won't move if it doesn't it will move

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Level33DragSystem : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    Vector2 mprevpos = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 mPosDelta = Vector2.zero;
    float rota;
    bool drag;
    void Start()
    {

    }
    private RectTransform rectTransform;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }
    //Mouse Hareketi , Telefon ve Bilgisayar için 
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {



        if (!drag)
        {
            if (rota < 13)
            {
                rota = rota + 0.5f;
                //rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta;
                mPosDelta = eventData.delta - mprevpos;
                transform.Rotate(0, 0, rota, Space.Self);
            }
            else
            {
                this.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180);
                Invoke("Bekle", 3f);


            }
        }
        else
        {

            rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta;
        }


    }
    public void Bekle()
    {
        drag = true;
        this.gameObject.name = "6";

    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {

        if (collision.tag == "Sayi1")
        {
            this.gameObject.transform.position = collision.transform.position;
            this.GetComponent<Level33DragSystem>().enabled = false;
            GameObject.Find("Sayı1").GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().isTrigger = false;
            GameObject.Find("Sayı1").GetComponent<Text>().text = this.gameObject.name;
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().toplam = GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().toplam + int.Parse(this.gameObject.name);
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().eklenen = GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().eklenen + 1;
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().ControlTwenty();
        }
        if (collision.tag == "Sayi2")
        {
            this.gameObject.transform.position = collision.transform.position;
            this.GetComponent<Level33DragSystem>().enabled = false;
            GameObject.Find("Sayı2").GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().isTrigger = false;
            GameObject.Find("Sayı2").GetComponent<Text>().text = this.gameObject.name;
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().toplam = GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().toplam + int.Parse(this.gameObject.name);
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().eklenen = GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().eklenen + 1;
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().ControlTwenty();
            
        }
        if (collision.tag == "Sayi3")
        {
            this.gameObject.transform.position = collision.transform.position;
            this.GetComponent<Level33DragSystem>().enabled = false;
            GameObject.Find("Sayı2").GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().isTrigger = false;
            GameObject.Find("Sayı3").GetComponent<Text>().text = this.gameObject.name;
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().toplam = GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().toplam + int.Parse(this.gameObject.name);
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().eklenen = GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().eklenen + 1;
            GameObject.Find("Level 33").GetComponent<FindTwenty>().ControlTwenty();
        }

    }
    private void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: @maksymiuk this my script

Comment: Don't you know the answer?